# Rigify error: Generation has thrown the exception 'None Type' object has no attribute 'bones'

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have the same problem, but here the spine bone is set up correctly, so are all the other bones. This MetaRig is made of 2 rigs, a face rig that I did earlier, then I made a new MetaRig which I combined with the face rig correctly. Earlier I was getting the error saying *spine.004* was disjoint, but I fixed that by connecting it to *spine.003* using the connect button.

Any suggestions? As you can see it is set to *spine.basic_spine*:
[image: screenshot 1]

Answer (score 0):

Your fix for "Spine.004 is disjoint" was not exactly a fix. It just removed the error message and created further problems. It's not your fault, Rigify setups are just easily messed up with by making small changes.

- parent the neck back to Spine.004
- snap the neck bone to the end of the spine
  [image]

If you have trouble snapping the bones together, here is how to do it:

https://youtu.be/ILDdIbAwxJM?t=490